# dyld: Library not loaded: when adding SwiftSyntax via SPM

Tags: macos, swift-package-manager

I did the following:

1. Create a new macOS project.
2. Include a dependency on https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax.git via Swift Package Manager.
3. Choose exact version and use version number `0.50300.0` (since I'm using Xcode 12.4 and that is the highest version supported).

When I launch the app, I get the runtime error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
>
> Referenced from: ....
>
> Reason: image not found

The [readme mentions](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax#embedding-swiftsyntax-in-an-application) that:

> SwiftSyntax depends on the lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib/.so library which provides a C interface to the underlying Swift C++ parser. When you do swift build SwiftSyntax links and uses the library included in the Swift toolchain. If you are building an application make sure to embed _InternalSwiftSyntaxParser as part of your application's libraries.
>
> You can either copy lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib/.so directly from the toolchain...

How can I find this file in the toolchain?

How do I "embed _InternalSwiftSyntaxParser"?

Comment: Open xcodeproj generated by `swift package generate-xcodeproj` rather than opening your project directly. You'd loose the advantage of Xcode's SwiftPM integration, though...

Answer (score 8):

1. Find the file in your toolchain by locating it within the Xcode.app bundle:

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
   ```
2. Copy this file to your Xcode project's directory.
3. Drag the file into the Project navigator in Xcode.

   This should automatically add it to your target's Frameworks and Libraries.
4. Under your target's settings, change `lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib` to "Embed and Sign".